# Invalid json getting parse using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I am using JavaScriptSerializer class for convert json string to object

If I append(10.), for int value, symbols like '.','@' etc still it getting correct json, Actually its not valid json file.
I have check this json string using different ways, but it is not valid all the way.

Not understand its behavior.

It should take only '10' for integer.

Code snippet :

```
class Emp 
{        
    public string firstName
    {
        get;set;
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        set;get;
    }
    public int Id
    {
        set;get;
    }
}

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Type t = typeof(Emp);
var returnType = serializer.Deserialize<Emp>("{'firstName': 'John','lastName':'Doe','id': 10.}");
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: "{'firstName': 'John','lastName':'Doe','id': 10.}" this is not valid json ojbect, But still its getting parse.

Comment: The only invalid part are the single quotes. I assume that the `JavaScriptSerializer` knowingly accepts that and still parses it when it can.

Comment: Yes that I can understand, But still this is not valid input for int(10.). But JavaScriptSerializer should throw error.

Comment: Any other class that can be use to json conversion.

Comment: JSON, like JavaScript, does not differentiate between integers and other non-integer numbers. It only knows numbers and for them `10.` is the same as `10`. So the deserializer only sees the “number” (actually it’s always like a double), and checks whether it could write it into the target `int` property. If that works (because the double happens to be an integer), then that’s fine.

Comment: If json consider 10. as a double then 10.0 should be same, But its not works for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that come into play here:

The only actually *invalid* part of that JSON are its quotation marks. [JSON](http://json.org/) actually only allows strings enquoted by double quotation marks, so it’s maybe a bit odd that the `JavaScriptSerializer` supports deserializing single quotation marks.

This is a deliberate choice to support multiple alternative formats. The [underlying deserializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,184) actually even supports leaving out the quotation marks for property names, so the following would be valid too (which makes sense given that it’s also a valid JavaScript expression):

```
{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', id: 10. }
```

The other part which you mentioned is that `10.` number which is not an integer but is deserialized just fine *as* an integer. This is because JSON—like JavaScript—only knows about numbers. There is no difference between integers and non-integers; there is only a single number type which is an [IEEE-754 floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), like .NET’s double.

So when deserializing, the base type cannot be taken into account since that would always be a double. But the [underlying deserializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,221) actually does attempt to get some information from the actual string representation. So a value of `10` would return an integer, while a value of `10.` would return a decimal.

However, when that information is then used and [applied to the target type](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,38) that restriction is loosened, and a [converter is used](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/ObjectConverter.cs,345) to convert the decimal into the int—since the decimal `10.0` would fit in an int.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a valid JSON has double quotes so the input should be following:

```
var returnType2 = serializer.Deserialize<Emp>(@"{""firstName"": ""John"",""lastName"":""Doe"",""id"": 10}");
```

As for the validation part please check the [MSDN JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation. You can see that all the primitive numeric (or numeric-compatible) types like Byte, Ints, uInts etc. are equivalent to JSON Number. While Number (as per JSON schema) is a double precision floating-point format in Javascript thus `"id":10.` is perfectly valid and `JavaScriptSerializer` must be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Json object format isnt correct. Simple quotes outside for string format and, double inside the object.  Read http://www.w3schools.com/json/
You can validate here 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com